# How to set value in RatingBar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello i want to set value in `RatingBar` in `Android` but don't do nothing.

This is my code.

```
RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
if(GameViewMoon.Valorbadg == 4)
{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.levelfive, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      ratingbar.setRating(4);
      GameViewMoon.Valorbadg = 0;
}
```

**XML**

```
 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="2.0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_current_score_value"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: do you see the toast? you don't see the rating bar at all or you just don't see the new value?

Comment: I see the toast but dont see the rating bar value

Comment: can you post your layout xml please

Comment: the whole thing...

Comment: Why need the whole thing?

Comment: because if you don't see the ratingbar it might be because the layout is messed up

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to start using the new **AppCompatRatingBar** that have support for new and old devices. Here is the documentation in case you need it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRatingBar.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ratingBar.setIsIndicator(true) after setting the value.